# Divide operation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database in which a table employee exist as follow

```
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| LastName  | DepartmentID | projectname |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
| Rafferty  |           31 |  ims        |
| Jones     |           33 |  ibm server |
| Steinberg |           33 |  null       |
| Robinson  |           34 |  ims        |
| Smith     |           34 |  ibmserver  |
| John      |         NULL |  ims        |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+
```

i want to retrieve those last name who work on a project on which jones working

```
Select * from employee ???
```

any suggestion please

Comment: Dividing the table its a part of join operation i was studying relational algebra and want to apply this on MySQL

Comment: Given your example data, there are *no* other employees working with Jones. He's working on a project called `ibm server`. There's no one else on that project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following should be your query -

```
Select * from employee where projectname = (select projectname from employee where LastName = 'Jones');
```

We have not used `in` clause as Jones is working in one project.

If he is working in multiple projects

then query can be -

```
Select * from employee where projectname in (select projectname from employee where LastName = 'Jones');
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did anyone ever bother inventing JOINs?